# Can't seem to understand why tf.contrib.layers.zeros_initializer() gives an Aterror

Tags: python, tensorflow

Two dictionaries defining weights and biases for the CNN

```
weights = {
#Convolution Layers
'c1': tf.get_variable('W1', shape=(3,3,1,16), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
'c2': tf.get_variable('W2', shape=(3,3,16,16), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
'c3': tf.get_variable('W3', shape=(3,3,16,32), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
'c4': tf.get_variable('W4', shape=(3,3,32,32), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),

#Dense Layers
'd1': tf.get_variable('W5', shape=(7*7*32,128), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
'd2': tf.get_variable('W6', shape=(128,n_class), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
}

biases = {
#Convolution Layers
'c1': tf.get_variable('B1', shape=(16), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.zeros_initializer()),
'c2': tf.get_variable('B2', shape=(16), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.zeros_initializer()),
'c3': tf.get_variable('B3', shape=(32), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.zeros_initializer()),

#Dense Layers
'd1': tf.get_variable('B5', shape=(128), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.zeros_initializer()),
'd2': tf.get_variable('B6', shape=(n_class), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.zeros_initializer()),
}
```

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'zeros_initializer'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was deprecated, use `keras.initializers.zeros`

```
a = tf.get_variable('B1', shape=(16), initializer=tf.keras.initializers.zeros())
```

Or you can still access the old function with compat module

```
a = tf.get_variable('B1', shape=(16,), initializer=tf.compat.v1.zeros_initializer())
```

Comment: It now gives another error:

        1 weights = {
        2     #Convolution Layers
----> 3     'c1': tf.get_variable('W1', shape=(3,3,1,16), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),                                                                                                                                                                ValueError: Variable W1 already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope? Originally defined at:

Comment: This is some variable conflict, try setting to tf.AUTO_REUSE. But it has nothing to do with initializer

Comment: Where should I put that statement?

Comment: It depends on what is in your code. Maybe you have `with tf.variable_scope(reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)`

Comment: I'm so done, Google Colab started giving shitty syntax errors even for = signs and curly brackets of dictionaries. I'm going to try this in my IDE

Comment: Ok, turns out that the google collaboratory notebook was running tf 2.0 alpha in which the module tf.contrib has been removed. Thanks for answering and sorry if my question was silly, I am new to low-level ANNs